# Empty deleted items for an 0365 Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-office-365, hosted-exchange

Please advise of there is a way to empty the deleted items folder of an office365 mailbox. This is not an on-premise exchange, all hosted in microsoft.

I have tried this command:

```
Search-mailbox -identity <username> -TargetMailbox "inbox" -Targetfolder "Deleted Items" -DeleteContent -Verbose
```

It does not work. It executes but does not have any effect on the deleted items folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change the default email retention for deleted items in Office 365. Not a long time ago, it was 30 days by default, but Microsoft decided to change it to something like "Keep Forever".

> **Create a custom retention policy**
>
> You can either edit the name of the Default MRM Policy or create a new
>   policy to opt out of this change. To change the policy name in Office
>   365 navigate to **Office 365 Admin > Exchange admin center > compliance
>   management > retention policies.** Next, select Default MRM Policy,
>   click the edit icon and then change the name of the policy.

https://blogs.office.com/2015/02/20/extended-email-retention-deleted-items-office-365/

Answer (score 1):

The way you have structured your command is incorrect.  `TargetMailbox` and `TargetFolder` specify the destination where search results are copied.  This is typically a Discovery Mailbox or similar.

What you have specified will look in the mailbox `<username>` copy **all** content (no query or other criteria is specified) to a mailbox called `Inbox`, in a folder called `Deleted Items`.  Everything in the mailbox `<username>` should have been deleted from the source mailbox and copied to the `Inbox` mailbox (should it exist, I think this would have thrown an error).

Please review TechNet for Search-Mailbox: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx

You will want something like the following:

`Search-Mailbox -Identity source.mailbox@domain.com -SearchDumpsterOnly -DeleteContent`

Now, I should clarify:  This would **permanently delete** the contents of the `Recoverable Items` folder, a hidden system folder where things go **AFTER** they disappear from `Deleted Items`.  If Legal Holds are employed, all bets are off and it is entirely possible/likely content could still be discovered, depending on the holds employed.